# How can I use \patchcmd with commands with optional arguments?

Tags: macros, etoolbox, optional-arguments

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)

This is likely a simple question, but I'm getting stuck on the small details.  I have an internal command, defined by a package as

```
\newcommand\foo@[3][]{...stuff...}
```

and somewhere in there I'd like to patch the command to include a call to `\label{#1}`.  I'm already using `etoolbox`, so I planned to use

```
\patchcmd{\foo@}{hook}{\label{#1}hook}{success}{failure}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because `\foo@` is defined as

```
> \foo@=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \foo@ \\foo@ {}.
l.359 \show\foo@
```

Which has no parameters and therefore the patching code fails.  So I tried to figure out how to get `\\foo@`  (note the doubled slash and the trailing space) as a csname, and I got snarled up.

So then I tried using the old-style approach of `\let\my@foo@=\foo@\renewcommand\foo@[3][]{...\my@foo@[#1]{#2}{#3}` -- I know the original idiom is to use `\let` and `\def`, but since `\foo@` was defined with `\newcommand` I tried using `\renewcommand`.  But this doesn't work, and fails with a TeX capacity exceeded error, and the log file appears to show an endless cycle of macro expansion.

**So**.  What is the correct name for the internal macro defined by `\newcommand` when optional arguments are present, and how do I build the csname for that so I can patch it with `\patchcmd`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get `\\foo@` using `\csname\string\foo@\endcsname`. The space shown behind it with `\show` is not part of the macro name (but could be added using a `\space` before `\endcsname`).
So you can use:

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\foo@\endcsname{hook}{\label{#1}hook}{success}{failure}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo@[3][]{stuff (#1) more stuff :#2: hook even more stuff = *#3*}

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\foo@\endcsname{hook}{\label{#1}hook}{success}{failure}

\texttt{\string\foo@ = \meaning\foo@}

\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname\string\foo@\endcsname = \expandafter\meaning\csname\string\foo@\endcsname}

\makeatother


\section{Test}
\makeatletter
\foo@[test]{One}{Two}
\makeatother

\section{Test2}
See section \ref{test}!

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, that works.  (Well, with the slight tweak that I need a trailing space, so `\csname\string\foo@ \endcsname`, but the `\string` command was what I was missing)

Comment: I don't see why you need the space. `\show` places one space after every control sequence (aka macro), so there would be two after ``\\foo@`` if it would include one space. I know that robust commands use a trailing space in the internal macro name, but this isn't used here.

Comment: @Ben Lerne: besides, the space before `\endcsname` in your comment is ignored by TeX, since it follows a control word.

Answer (score 21):

***NOTE***: There are some minor weaknesses in the code shown below, so it's best to use the corresponding package.

---

The following macros define the commands `\xpatchcmd`, `\xpretocmd` and `\xapptocmd` that recognize robust commands (defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` or `\newrobustcmd`) and also if they have an optional argument.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% generate a variant of \tl_if_in:NnT
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:NnT { Nx }
% a boolean for testing robust commands
\bool_new:N \l_xpatch_protect_bool
% a "bizarre" token list that's quite improbable to find in a replacement text
\tl_set:Nx \c_xpatch_bizarre_tl { \tl_to_str:n { **)-(**/**[-]** } }
% the main command; it takes as first argument one of \patchcmd, \pretocmd or
% \apptocmd; the second argument is the command we want to patch
\cs_new:Npn \xpatchcmd_main:NN #1 #2
  {
% first of all we gather the command-to-patch name
   \tl_set:Nx \l_xpatch_name_tl { \exp_after:wN \use_none:n \token_to_str:N #2  }
% now we get the replacement text of the command-to-patch, but adding the bizarre
% token list in front of it which consists of all category 12 characters
   \tl_set:Nx \l_xpatch_tmpa_tl { \c_xpatch_bizarre_tl \token_get_replacement_spec:N #2 }
% now we look whether the token list contains the bizarre list followed by \protect
% which happens if it's a control sequence defined by \DeclareRobustCommand, so
% we add a space to the command name
   \tl_if_in:NxT \l_xpatch_tmpa_tl { \c_xpatch_bizarre_tl \token_to_str:N \protect} 
     {
      \bool_set_true:N \l_xpatch_protect_bool 
      \xpatch_add_space:
     }
% now we look whether the token list contains the bizarre list followed by \x@protect
% which happens if it's a control symbol defined by \DeclareRobustCommand, so
% we add a space to the command name
   \tl_if_in:NxT \l_xpatch_tmpa_tl { \c_xpatch_bizarre_tl \token_to_str:N \x@protect} 
     {
      \bool_set_true:N \l_xpatch_protect_bool
      \xpatch_add_space:
     }
% now we look whether the token list contains the bizarre list followed by \@protected@testopt
% which happens if it's a command with an optional argument (from \newcommand)
   \tl_if_in:NxT \l_xpatch_tmpa_tl { \c_xpatch_bizarre_tl \token_to_str:N \@protected@testopt} 
     { \xpatch_add_backslash: }
% now we look whether the token list contains the bizarre list followed by \@testopt
% which happens if it's a command with an optional argument (from \newrobustcmd)
   \tl_if_in:NxT \l_xpatch_tmpa_tl { \c_xpatch_bizarre_tl \token_to_str:N \@testopt} 
     { \xpatch_add_backslash: }
% if the command-to-patch was defined by \DeclareRobustCommand we look whether the
% command name with backslash in front and space at the end exists and we assume that
% it has an optional argument
   \bool_if:NT \l_xpatch_protect_bool 
     {
      \cs_if_exist:cT { \c_backslash_tl \l_xpatch_name_tl }
        { \xpatch_add_backslash: }
     }
% now we pass the real command-to-patch name to the patching macro
   \exp_after:wN #1 \cs:w \l_xpatch_name_tl \cs_end:
  }
% how we add a space after the name
\cs_new:Npn \xpatch_add_space: 
  { \tl_set:Nx \l_xpatch_name_tl { \l_xpatch_name_tl \c_space_tl } }
% how we add a backslash in front of the name
\cs_new:Npn \xpatch_add_backslash:
  { \tl_set:Nx \l_xpatch_name_tl { \c_backslash_tl \l_xpatch_name_tl } }
% a constant containing a backslash (category 12)
\tl_set:Nx \c_backslash_tl { \exp_after:wN \use_none:n \token_to_str:N \\ }
% the user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\xpatchcmd}{}{ \xpatchcmd_main:NN \patchcmd }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xpretocmd}{}{ \xpatchcmd_main:NN \pretocmd }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xapptocmd}{}{ \xpatchcmd_main:NN \apptocmd }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xshowcmd}{}{ \xpatchcmd_main:NN \show }


\NewDocumentCommand{\xpatchbibmacro} { m }
  { \exp_after:wN \xpatchcmd_main:NN \exp_after:wN \patchcmd \cs:w abx@macro@ \tl_to_str:n {#1} \cs_end: }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xpretobibmacro} { m }
  { \exp_after:wN \xpatchcmd_main:NN \exp_after:wN \pretocmd \cs:w abx@macro@ \tl_to_str:n {#1} \cs_end: }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xapptobibmacro} { m }
  { \exp_after:wN \xpatchcmd_main:NN \exp_after:wN \apptocmd \cs:w abx@macro@ \tl_to_str:n {#1} \cs_end: }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xshowbibmacro} { m }
  { \exp_after:wN \xpatchcmd_main:NN \exp_after:wN \show \cs:w abx@macro@ \tl_to_str:n {#1} \cs_end: }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Of course commands defined in a devious way can break these macros, but this is true of almost any set of macros.

Patching commands defined by `\NewDocumentCommand` or the others provided by `xparse` is *not* supported.

### Usage

```
\newcommand\foo[3][]{...hook...}
\xpatchcmd{\foo}{hook}{\label{#1}hook}{success}{failure}

\xshowcmd\foo
```

The last one shows the "real" meaning of `\foo`. The commands

```
\xpatchbibmacro \xpretobibmacro \xapptobibmacro
```

can be used to patch commands defined via `\newbibmacro` of `biblatex`; with `\xshowbibmacro` one can see the "real" meaning of the macro.

Answer (score 5):

To patch a command (with or without an optional argument) defined by means of `\newcommand` or `\DeclareRobustCommand`, I use a wrapper `\xpatchcmd` around `\patchcmd`. `\xpatchcmd` has an additional optional argument in front of the first argument of `\patchcmd` that indicates the nature of the command to be patched:

- `n` → `\newcommand`
- `o` → `\newcommand` + optional argument
- `N` → `\DeclareRobustCommand`
- `O` → `\DeclareRobustCommand` + optional argument

Definition and application of `\xpatchcmd`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\xpatchcmd}[1][]{%
  \bgroup%
  \let\@gobble@\@gobble\let\@space@\empty%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}\OR\equal{\unexpanded{#1}}{n}}{}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\unexpanded{#1}}{o}}{\let\@gobble@\empty}{%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\unexpanded{#1}}{N}}{\let\@space@\space}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\unexpanded{#1}}{O}}{\let\@gobble@\empty\let\@space@\space}{%
          \typeout{%
            Command \protect\xpatchcmd\space Warning: Invalid command specifier "\unexpanded{#1}".%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \catcode`\#=12%
  \@xpatchcmd%
}

\newcommand{\@xpatchcmd}[6][\undefined]{%
  \catcode`\#=6%
  \edef\undefined{\noexpand\undefined}%
  \def\@prefix{#1}%
  \letcs{\@command}{\expandafter\@gobble@\string#2\@space@}%
  \ifx\@prefix\undefined%
    \patchcmd{\@command}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \else%
    \patchcmd[\@prefix]{\@command}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi%
  \global\cslet{\expandafter\@gobble@\string#2\@space@}{\@command}%
  \egroup%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\test}[2]{#1me#2}
\show\test
\xpatchcmd[n][\protected]{\test}{me}{you}{}{}
\show\test

\renewcommand{\test}[2][]{#1me#2}
\expandafter\show\csname\string\test\endcsname
\xpatchcmd[o][]{\test}{me#2}{you#1}{}{}
\expandafter\show\csname\string\test\endcsname

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\test}[2]{#1me#2}
\expandafter\show\csname test \endcsname
\xpatchcmd[N][\long]{\test}{#1me}{#2you}{}{}
\expandafter\show\csname test \endcsname

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\test}[2][only]{#1me#2}
\expandafter\show\csname\string\test\space\endcsname
\xpatchcmd[O]{\test}{#2}{}{}{}
\expandafter\show\csname\string\test\space\endcsname

\end{document}
```