# Is there a \lowertitleback for \extratitle?

Tags: koma-script, titles

I am using the `koma` package to typeset my thesis and was wondering if there is something like "`\lowerextratitleback`", i.e. the analog of `\lowertitleback` for the extra title page which can be set using `\extratitle`, to put text on the backside of the extra titlepage?

Answer (score 4):

Now there is. :-) Note that `\extratitleback` will only be typeset if `\extratitle` isn't empty and `twoside` is enabled. This works for the `titlepage` as well as for the `notitlepage` class option. To patch `\maketitle` (which features an optional argument in KOMA-Script) I used the trick described by Martin Scharrer in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24249/510) answer.

EDIT: Replaced `\extratitleback` with `\upperextratitleback` and `\lowerextratitleback`. Note that -- corresponding to `KOMA-Script`s implementation of `\uppertitleback` and `\lowertitleback` -- the arguments of the new commands are typeset in `minipage`s, so the caveats for this environment apply (e.g., a `\parindent` of 0pt).

```
\listfiles

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@upperextratitleback}{}%
\newcommand{\upperextratitleback}[1]{\gdef\@upperextratitleback{%
    #1%
}}
\newcommand*{\@lowerextratitleback}{}%
\newcommand{\lowerextratitleback}[1]{\gdef\@lowerextratitleback{%
    #1%
}}
\newcommand*{\@makeextratitleback}{%
  \if@twoside
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      \@upperextratitleback
    \end{minipage}
    \par
    \vfill
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
      \@lowerextratitleback
    \end{minipage}
    \next@tpage
  \fi
}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\maketitle\endcsname{%
  \cleardoubleemptypage
}{%
  \@makeextratitleback
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{%
  \if@twoside\null\next@tpage\fi
}{%
  \@makeextratitleback
}{}{}
\makeatother

\extratitle{Extratitle}
\upperextratitleback{Upperextratitleback}
\lowerextratitleback{Lowerextratitleback}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\uppertitleback{Uppertitleback}
\lowertitleback{Lowertitleback}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Here's my file list produced by adding `\listfiles` at the start of the example. Check if you're using the same versions.

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2011/05/30 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (type area)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
 ***********
```

Comment: The version before the edit worked fine, but I can't get the updated version to print the `Upperextratitleback` and `Lowerextratitleback` text.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Does my example work for you? If yes, you must be doing something different in your actual document.

Comment: No, it's the example that doesn't work. I've tried on two different machines but without success.

Comment: I am using v3.04a of KOMA-Script (3.03 / 3.03b for scrlfile.sty, tocbasic.sty) and v1.8 e-Tex tools. (Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Please upgrade your TeX distribution and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Since KOMA-Script 3.25, there has been a `\frontispiece` command that adds a page to the verso of `\extratitle`. This normally adds content to the top of the page without extra formatting, but one can add it to the foot using the `minipage` environment from the earlier answer:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\extratitle{My book}

\frontispiece{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      Upper extratitle text
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
      Lower extratitle text
    \end{minipage}
}

\title{My Book}
\subtitle{An Experiment}
\author{Author}
\date{2019}
\publishers{StackExchange}

\uppertitleback{Upper title page text}

\lowertitleback{Lower title page text}

\dedication{To all StackExchangers}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late, but it might help people who, like me, ended up here after a bit of searching.

I'm using KOMA to typeset a book for the first time. It's very impressive but I needed a page on the verso of the halftitle to put the author's 'also bys'. As noted above the command `\extratitleback` doesn't exist although it probably ought to.

I couldn't get lockstep's example to work either and I'm not smart enough to work out what is going wrong. I'm using TeXworks 0.6.1 under Windows 7.

However, there is a much simpler solution. It's just a question of using `\maketitle` twice.

(If there isn't a copyright page then insert a `\uppertitleback{}` before the second `\maketitle` otherwise there will be another page of also buys.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{a short story book}
\author{}
\date{}
\uppertitleback{\centering \rmfamily \scshape also by a n author\\
\medskip
\normalfont A N Other Of My Books\\
A N Other Of My Books\\

}
\maketitle[1]

\title{A Short Story Book}
\author{A. N. Author}
\date{}
\publishers{A N Press}
\uppertitleback{Copyright  Page}
\dedication{\emph{to the totally wonderful people in my life}}

\maketitle[3]

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Story}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn t it be much much much more easy to simply place the stuff yourself instead of fiddling with a layout another human has decided for? I find this so very confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I take your point. Usually I code from scratch but a colleague recommended KOMA as an aid to productivity and consistency and, by and large, I'm happy with it. The lack of a halftitle verso was the first issue I'd come across and, since it's needed in most books, I thought it was worth sharing the workaround. It's less of a sledgehammer than writing a whole new macro (which is also fiddling with another human's layout). However you are right, it's not that much more effort to do a stand alone halftitle and 'Also By'.