# biblatex: Is it possible to patch macros created with \newbibmacro?

Tags: macros, biblatex, etoolbox, patching

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)

The [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package provides various tools that *"are useful to hook into or modify existing code"* (`etoolbox` manual, section 3.4). The most important one is the `\patchcmd` command with the syntax

```
\patchcmd[<prefix>]{<command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

which *"extracts the replacement text of a `<command>`, replaces [the first occurence of] `<search>`
with `<replace>`, and reassembles the `<command>`"*. Other useful macros are, e.g., `\apptocmd` and `\pretocmd` which will append resp. prepend code to the replacement text of a command.

The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package features the commands `\newbibmacro`, `\renewbibmacro`, and `\providebibmacro` (plus their starred counterparts). These commands resemble `\newcommand`/`\renewcommand`/`\providecommand` "*except that [the command name] may contain characters such as numbers and punctuation marks and does not start with a backslash"* (`biblatex` manual, section 4.6.4). The "bibmacros" defined this way may be executed via `\usebibmacro{<command name>}`.

Is it possible to define a `\patchbibmacro` command that extracts and modifies the replacement text of macros created with `\newbibmacro` the same way `\patchcmd` does for macros created with `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\act@on@bibmacro#1#2{%
  \expandafter#1\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname}
\def\patchbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\patchcmd}
\def\pretobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\pretocmd}
\def\apptobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\apptocmd}
\def\showbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\show}
\makeatother
```

Now you have available

```
\patchbibmacro \pretobibmacro \apptobibmacro \showbibmacro
```

Explanation:

`\newbibmacro{foo}[1]{-#1-}` actually executes

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{foo}\endcsname[1]{-#1-}
```

(I omit some gory details, but this is almost the truth).

This, of course, won't work for macros with optional arguments, but here's how:

```
\makeatletter
\def\act@on@bibmacroopt#1#2{%
  \expandafter#1\csname\expandafter\string\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname\endcsname}
\def\patchbibmacroopt{\act@on@bibmacroopt\patchcmd}
\def\pretobibmacroopt{\act@on@bibmacroopt\pretocmd}
\def\apptobibmacroopt{\act@on@bibmacroopt\apptocmd}
\def\showbibmacroopt{\act@on@bibmacroopt\show}
\makeatother
```

With `\patchbibmacroopt` you can define `biblatex` macros defined for instance by

```
\newbibmacro{baz}[2][x]{-#1-#2-}
```

One has to remember that with `\newcommand{\baz}[2][x]{-#1-#2-}` the macro doing the real work is

```
\\baz
```

that, of course, has to be accessed with

```
\csname\string\baz\endcsname
```

### Easier solution

The question led to adding some features to the `xpatch` package, which now has

```
\xpatchbibmacro
\xpretobibmacro
\xapptobibmacro
```

which work out of the box even with bibmacros defined having an optional argument; the syntax is the same as the one for `\patchcmd`, `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd`:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{<name>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpretobibmacro{<name>}{<code to prepend>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xapptobibmacro{<name>}{<code to append>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

So, if `foo` has been defined with `\newbibmacro{foo}[1]{-#1-}` one can say, for instance,

```
\xpatchbibmacro{foo}{-}{+}{}{}
```

to change the first `-` into `+`.

Comment: Is there any case where using the `opt` variants is inadvisable?  If not, why not use just these variants (and rename them)?

Comment: For macros defined without optional arguments (`\newbibmacro{foo}[1]{...}`), you *mustn't* use the "opt" variant. It would be possible to catch this automatically, but it's complicated and I don't think it's worth a try. However, you can look for `xpatchcmd` on the site for an automatic solution that could be ported to this case.

Comment: Indeed - I just noticed that my "one size fits all" idea won't work.

Comment: Look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24377/4427 :)

Comment: @lockstep I've just uploaded the `xpatch` package that incorporates code for this kind of patching.