# Use et al. in biblatex custom style

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I have been working on a custom biblatex style, for which I want the bibliography to display at most 2 authors, meaning that the entries should be either:

- First (single author)
- First & Second (two authors)
- First et al. (three and more)

I came up with the following name format, to which I feed the first three authors using `\printnames[][1-3]{author}\space` in the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` commands.

```
%%%% authors
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}%
        {#1 \ifblank{#4}{}{\addcomma\space #4}}%
        {%
            \ifthenelse{\value{liststop}=2}%
                {\space\&\space\ifblank{#4}{}{#4\space}#1}%
                {%
                    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=3}%
                        {\space}%
                        {, et~al.}%
                }%
        }%
    }%
```

It's working just fine, but given that I intend to move to biblatex, I'd like to have a very clean code, so the question is basically: how can it be improved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about name lists for editors or translators? If you want to apply the same truncation throughout, just use the package option `maxnames=2`. The rest is achieved by redefining `\finalnamedelim` - a macro that sets the delimiter before the final item in a name list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{bertram,companion,jaffe,moraux}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above sample document applies the format in both citations and the bibliography. To limit it only to the bibliography, use the option `maxbibnames=2` and

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifbibliography
    {\addspace\&\space}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}
```

If you're really determined to define your own style, I'd use the generic name formats from `biblatex.def` as a starting point. Your format deviates from these in terms of name delimiters (`\bibnamedelim...`), name part format (`\mkbibname...`, casing, initials, order, etc.), elimination of spurious whitespace (`\addspace`) and localization (`\bibstring{andothers}`). Unless you apply similar formats to `editor`, `bookauthor`, `translator`, etc. your name lists will appear inconsistent.

Comment: @TimothéePoisot No problem. lockstep provides a nice introduction to customizing biblatex styles in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/4483). Making minor changes to bibliography macros and drivers is easy with egreg's [`xpatch` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705/4483).