# Bibliography styles like authordate2 in biblatex or natbib?

Tags: biblatex

I've tried using the `authordate2` style of bibtex which is really close of the styles I wanted for my dissertation but this package is really old. Trying with default styles the code worked well but with the `authordate2` style it says that `\cite{myref}` is an `Undefined control sequence`.

So I discovered `biblatex` and with it the citation styles already had the parentheses. I just wanted to change the "and" by "&", put the "et al" in italics and to wrap the name and the year by a hyperlink.

The bibliography style is a little more tricky but I believe someone more experienced in `biblatex` macros and stuff would know.

I'd like to get citation and bibliography styles like these:

Citation

> (Lastname & Lastname2, year)
>
> (Lastname *et al*, year; Lastname2 *et al*, year; Lastname & Lastname2, year)

Bibliography

> [Lastname & Lastname2, year]   F.M. Lastname & F.M. Lastname2. (2003). **Paper Title** . *Journal Name* . 98(462):470–487.
>
> [Lastname *et al*, year] F.M. Lastname, F.M. Lastname2 & F.M. Lastname3. (2003). **Paper Title** . *Journal Name* . 98(462):470–487.

Here's a minimal example from what I did until now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref=true,hyperref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@ARTICLE{citationA,
 Author = {Fulano Tal de Rio de Janeiro and Fulano Tal de Sao Paulo },
 Year = {2001},
 Title = {Paper Title},
 Journal = {Jornal A}
}

@ARTICLE{citationB,
 Author = {Fulano Tal de Rio de Janeiro and Fulano Tal de Sao Paulo and Fulano Tal de Recife     },
 Year = {2002},
 Title = {Paper Title},
 Journal = {Jornal B}
}

@ARTICLE{citationB2,
 Author = {Fulano Tal de Rio de Janeiro and Fulano Tal de Sao Paulo and Fulano Tal de Recife         },
 Year = {2002},
 Title = {Paper Title},
 Journal = {Jornal C}
}

@ARTICLE{citationC,
 Author = {Fulano Tal de Recife},
 Year = {2003},
 Title = {Paper Title},
 Journal = {Jornal D}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{citationA}

\cite{citationB}

\cite{citationB2}

\cite{citationC}

\parencite{citationA,citationC}

\parencite{citationB2}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

PARTIAL SOLUTION

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2,maxbibnames=3,backref=true,hyperref=true,dashed=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}  

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
 
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{% 
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}% 
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}% 
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{% 
     \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
     \usebibmacro{textcite}%
     \iffieldundef{postnote}% 
       {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
          {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
          {}}
       {}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textbf{#1}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{citationA}

\cite{citationB}

\cite{citationB2}

\cite{citationC}

\parencite{citationA,citationC}

\parencite{citationB2}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Updated Output.
[image: OUTPUT]

Missing only the links in front like this figure.
[image]

Comment: Existing answers address many of the style elements you're wanting: [name list truncation and final delimiter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44048), ["et al." in italics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40798/4483), [removing "In:"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/4483), [hyperlinking name and year](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27107/4483). In [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/4483), lockstep discusses name initials and order. The rest appears straightforward. I'm sure someone can help you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you Audrey. I've gone through these articles and solved a bunch of requirements. I had updated the description with a partial solution. Now its missing the links in front of each bibitem. I've seen styles using numbers and the initial letters from authors in biblatex. I'll try to achieve the final result based on them. Have you seen if someone already tried something like that? Thanks again.

Comment: +1 No problem. The back references ("ver p. 1") can actually print a list of page numbers where the entry is cited. In the example would you want "Zhang *et al.*, 2004" to be a link back to the page where the entry is first cited?

Comment: Well, its not mandatory putting links in the back. I just put that backref=true so the navigation in the eletronically version of the dissertation would be easier. Let's say that the back references got into the list of requirements now. What I really wanted is the front links like in the image [Zhang et al., 2004].

Comment: I see that, but you're calling it a "link". If you mean that text should be hyperlinked, you need to tell us where this link should point to.

Comment: Oh sorry, The front "link" is not hyperlinked. From now on I'll call it the front labels, ok?

Comment: I have found a solution for the front labels here [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries). Almost done. I'm looking for a way to align the labels and the reference like in the image.

Comment: That problem isn't trivial to solve, especially if you want the alignment to change at every entry. Perhaps you could edit your question so that this post gets some more attention. (BTW: Now that you have enough rep you should consider upvoting all these questions and answers that have helped you so far.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've finished. It's not a perfect solution but it clears a lot of customization in `biblatex`. The `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` was got from the alphabetic/numeric styles and mixed with some code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries). I set the length of `\labelwidth` to 130pt so it would fit my needs. In the alphabetic/numeric styles these width are adjusted automatically. Maybe someone can achieve a better solution related to that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2,maxbibnames=3,maxcitenames=2,backref=true,hyperref=true,dashed=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}  

% putting & as the separator of the author name's
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
% the comma after the authors
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% no 'in'
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

% et al in italic
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

%  citation including both name and year
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{% 
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}% 
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}
         {\printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

%  text citation including both name and year
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}% 
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{% 
     \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{default}%
     \usebibmacro{textcite}%
     \iffieldundef{postnote}% 
       {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
          {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
          {}}
       {}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}}

    \newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
    }

% the bold title in article's entries
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textbf{#1}}

% order first name then last name 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

% the front labels before the bibliography references
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {
        \printtext[brackets]{%
            \begingroup
            \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
            \printfield{labelyear}% 
            \printfield{extrayear}%
            \endgroup
            }%
        }
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{130pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hfill##1\hss}
      }
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{citationA}

\cite{citationB}

\cite{citationB2}

\cite{citationC}

\parencite{citationA,citationC}

\parencite{citationB2}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The final output.

[image]

Just want to emphasize that most of the code were obtained from the links in Audrey's first comment.

Comment: +1 `maxnames=n` is a shorthand for `maxbibnames=n,maxcitenames=n`. Automatically setting the label width was the nontrivial problem I was referring to in my last comment. It's easy with `labelnumber` and `labelalpha` because they are internally defined as fields. Your label is the result of many formatting commands, so its width is hard to capture. This might get resolved with future `biblatex`/`biber` features.