# Biblatex alphabetic style like [Smith, 2005]

Tags: biblatex

the *alphabetic* style of biblatex is already very close to my requirements, but considering the following entry

```
@BOOK{smith1,
  author = {John Smith and Mike Someone},
  title = {The book with a very very very very very long title},
  year = {2005},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  location = {New York}
}
```

I would like to have a label like **[Smith, 2005]** instead of [Smi+05]. In other words:

```
[<first author's last name>, <year with 4 digits>]
```

In case there is more than one entry with the same author and the same year, a single letter should be added right behind the year like in **[Smith, 2005a]** (*alphabetic* already does this by default).

Comment: That looks much more like an author-year style to me, only with square brackets. Have you tried that? Have you looked at this answer for changing the bracket shape (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/biblatex-author-year-square-brackets)?

Comment: I already tried that, but the format of the bibliography entries is nearly exactly what I want when I use "alphabetic", whereas "authoryear" would need to be modified in this regard as well. I just thought it would be easier to choose the style that comes closest to my requirements in order to modify as little as possible :).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With `biblatex 2+` and `biber 1+` you can customize alphabetic labels with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{labelname}
    \field{label}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{,\addhighpenspace}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,baez/article,baez/online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple notes:

- The argument to `\literal` should be defined globally. Typically we specify one or more characters. We can also use `biblatex`'s whitespace commands. Unlike `biblatex`'s punctuation commands (e.g. `\addcomma`), they aren't restricted to citations and bibliographies.
- Similar results could be obtained with BibTeX by modifying an author-year style (e.g. [Bibliography styles like authordate2 in biblatex or natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44801/4483)), but getting the right item label alignment in the bibliography isn't easy.

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much :-).

Comment: @ph4nt0m don't forget to upvote Audrey's answer using the up arrow- this gives her 10 reputation points

Comment: I would love to do this, but "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :-(