# these-like BibLaTeX style

Tags: biblatex

The title is pretty-much self-explanatory: I'm searching for a BibLaTeX (not BibTeX) style that would give such a result: http://books.google.pl/books?id=5iBGig7WzV4C&lpg=PP1&hl=pl&pg=PA207#v=onepage&q&f=false .
For BiBTeX there's the these style (which is almost perfect, were it not for the shortening of the years): http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf but I didn't find anything even distinctly similar for BibLaTeX (and I can't use BibTeX in my work since it has problems with ancient greek symbols in titles). So my question stands as in the title: is there a these-like BibLaTeX style? Or at least could you provide me with some hint which style would be the closest one to what I'm searching for and then with what commands I could tailor it to my needs? Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:
The requested picture(s):

- the exact result I want to achieve:

[image: image1]

- what these-style gives me but BibLaTeX cannot:

[image: image2]

Comment: I can't see the relevant pages in the book. Can you upload a screenshot of the relevant page? As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again until you get more rep points.

Comment: The short answer is: "Yes". You'll have an easier time arriving to the long answer by demonstrating some effort in achieving the style you need. [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68862/4483) should help you get started with the labels.

Comment: According to http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/node22.html, better write everything in your *.bib files in plain ASCII (yes, that is probably horrible for Greek titles...)

Comment: @vonbrand biblatex and biber support UTF8.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks a lot! Had I found this topic earlier (only when I searched, I searched for "these" and such similar keywords), I probably would not have posted this question. I arrived exactly at what I wanted so I'll be answering my own question soon.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Audrey I'm able to answer my own question:

The tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,french,polish]{babel}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
\labelelement{
\field[final]{shorthand}
\field{labelname}
\field{label}
}
\labelelement{
\literal{\addhighpenspace}
}
\labelelement{
\field{year}
}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The biblatex-examples.bib file:

```
@book{cary1847,
title = {Memoir of the Rev. Henry Francis Cary, M. A., translator of Dante: With his   literary journal and letters},
author = {Henry Francis Cary},
number = 2,
lccn = {sd18000067},
series = {Memoir of the Rev. Henry Francis Cary, M. A., Translator of Dante: With His Literary Journal and Letters},
url = {http://books.google.pl/books?id=iD4OAAAAYAAJ},
year = 1847,
publisher = {E. Moxon}
}
@article{tobin2004,
author = {Ronald W. Tobin},
title = {Silent Witness: Racine's Non-verbal Annotations of Euripides (review)},
journal = {L'Esprit Createur},
year = 2004,
volume = 44,
number = 2,
url = {10.1353/esp.2010.0432}
}
@article{barone1987,
author = {Caterina Barone},
title = {L'{\greektext{>apaid'ia}} in Euripide: terminologia specifica},
journal = {Materiali e discussioni per l'analisi dei testi classici},
year = 1987,
number = 18,
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/40235880}
}
```

It reproduces exactly the result I wanted to achieve. However I found two addditional problems on the way but I think that they need they own questions...