# How to force references come up as et al

Tags: bibtex, natbib, author-number, harvard-style

I'm using natbib referencing, in agsm style. I have had no problem so far with it suppressing articles with 3 or more authors to et al. However for some papers it prints all the author names for my in text citations, like this (Bell, 2004; Bell, McGrath, Biggerstaff, Bates, Bennett, Marlow and Shaffer, 2015). I would prefer that it read Bell et al 2015 but I'm unsure how to force it to do this when none of my other references are any different but come out fine.

Comment: You can do it with biblatex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44048/use-et-al-in-biblatex-custom-style Also, a MWE would help getting a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should check first if you're loading the `natbib` package with the option `longnamesfirst`. If so, be sure to delete this option.

Since the `agsm` bibliography style is part of the `harvard` citation management package, you should load the package `har2nat` if you want to use the `agsm` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package. With `har2nat` loaded, the behavior of the `natbib`-based citation commands -- including the truncation of lists of three or more authors to "FirstAuthor et al" -- should work without problems.

The result of an MWE that loads the `har2nat` package:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{bell:2004,
  author = "Bell",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year  = 2004,
}
@misc{bell-etal:2015,
  author = "Bell and McGrath and Biggerstaff and Bates and Bennett and Marlow and Shaffer",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  year  = 2015,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % optional
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{har2nat} % natbib is loaded automatically by har2nat

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citep{bell:2004,bell-etal:2015}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem, so I used the bibliography style file "model5-names.bst" from Elsevier article style. The full zip exists here:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip
Once the zip file is extracted. Copy  "model5-names.bst" to your latex file directory and add:
\bibliographystyle{model5-names.bst}
to your latex file. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, you can modify your bib file. Use something like

```
authors_full = {{your} and {full} and {author} and {list}}
```

for the original author list and

```
author = {first \textit[et al.}}
```

for the short list.

Comment: Is this suggestion compatible with the `agsm` bibliography style and the `natbib` citation management package?