# Need help configuring entry type driver for biblatex-dw. Different citation style sa for different entry types

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

I need some help rewriting a bibliography driver. But lets start from the beginning:

I'm using `biblatex` with the `biblatex-dw` style. In the footnotes my cites appear as `name` `shorttitle` and `page`

Additionally to the usual literature i work with a lot of unpublished material from archives. My problem is the organization of these sources.

They do not have a name at all, but are handled alone by their signature. There is always the name of the archive, the category, the subcategory and the box number:

For example:  `Archiv Newtown` `Dep 1` `Ru 4` `354` (No commata between the single parts)

So everytime such a unpublished source is used, the full signature has to appear in the footnote. And of course in the bibliography the sources should be in the right alphanumerical order.

Another point is, that in the citations within the text the `Ibid.` function should work. I mean if use the same source two times in a row it should give out `Ibid.` What i do not need is `Ibid.` within the signature (If e.g. the category, subcategory or box changes).

So within the text it should look like

```
--------------------------------------------
1 ArchNew Ho1 Ru8 356.
2 Mueller 1994, p. 18.
3 ArchNew Ho1 Ru8 356.
4 Ibid.
5 ArchNew FAS Ru7 321
```

and in the bibliography

```
**Literature**

Mueller, Claus: Something. Berlin 1994

**Sources**

*Archive Newtown*

ArchNew Ho1 Ru8 356
ArchNew FAS Ru7 321
```

I found a thread with nearly the same problem and a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129788/different-citation-styles-for-different-entry-types-in-the-footnotes-biblatex-d/), but I I' afraid I couldn't rewrite the code over there to match my needs.

The difference is that in this solution over there, the sources also have names and are therefore handled both by their name AND their signature. I only need the signature.

Additionally i also need another subcategory since my signatures are longer. Maybe i could use the now free name field for this purpose?

Could anybody help me out here? I'd be really, really grateful.

The code i need to alter looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle-dw,
    firstfull=true
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  chapter = {Bd.}
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifentrytype{unpublished}%
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\and\not\iffirstonpage}%
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}{\usebibmacro{cite:firstfull}}}%
     {\ifbool{cbx:firstfull}%
        {\ifciteseen%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:firstfull}}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}%
  \usebibmacro{savestuff}%  
}

\newbibmacro{savestuff}{%
  \savelist{institution}{\lastinstitution}%
  \savelist{location}{\lastlocation}%
  \savefield{chapter}{\lastchapter}}

\xapptobibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{savestuff}}{}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{unpublished}{%
  \iffirstonpage{\def\lastinstitution{}%
    \def\lastlocation{}%
    \def\lastchapter{}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iflistequals{institution}{\lastinstitution}%
    {\bibstring{ibidem}%
     \newunit\newblock%
     \iflistequals{location}{\lastlocation}%
       {\iffieldequals{chapter}{\lastchapter}%
         {}{\printfield{chapter}}}%
       {\printlist{location}\newunit\newblock%
        \iffieldequals{chapter}{\lastchapter}%
          {\bibstring{ibidem}}%
          {\printfield{chapter}}}%
    }%
    {\printlist{institution}\newunit\newblock%
     \iflistequals{location}{\lastlocation}%
       {\bibstring{ibidem}\newunit\newblock%
         \iffieldequals{chapter}{\lastchapter}%
           {}{\printfield{chapter}}}%
       {\printlist{location}\newunit\newblock%
        \iffieldequals{chapter}{\lastchapter}%
          {\bibstring{ibidem}}%
          {\printfield{chapter}}}%
    }%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@unpublished {test1,
    title = {subcategory},
    institution = {Archive 1},
    location = {Category 1,
    chapter = {Box1}
}

@unpublished {test2,
    title = {subcategory},
    institution = {Archive 1},
    location = {Category 1},
    chapter = {Box2}
}

@unpublished {test3,
    title = {subcategory},
    institution = {Archive 1,
    location = {Category 2},
    chapter = {Box2}
}

@article{test4,
  title={Something},
  author={Mueller, Claus}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\footcite{test1}
\footcite{test1}
\footcite{test4}
\footcite{test1}
\footcite{test2}
\footcite{test3}
\footcite{test1}
\footcite{test4}
\clearpage
\footcite{test1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you would benefit from creating a new entry type `@archive` that can take `archivename`, `category`, `subcategory` and `boxnumber` as fields (and allow for short versions of these fields if necessary). The `ibid` part should be straightforward.

Comment: PS: The redefinition `chapter = {Bd.}` looks pretty fishy to me. Why do you need that?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in my comment above, I think it is beneficial to create a new entry type `@archive` that is tailored exactly to your needs.

We will have to create a new data model file `archives.dbx`, put it somewhere LaTeX can find it (the same directory as your current file will certainly do).

```
\ProvidesFile{archives.dbx}[2014/04/02 supplement archive]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{category,subcategory,archive,box}
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[archive]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{archive}
    \constraintfield{category}
    \constraintfield{box}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{category}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{category}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{subcategory}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{subcategory}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{box}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{box}
\endinput
```

We define a new entry type `@archive` that takes the fields `archive`, `category`, `box` and `subcategory` (the former three are mandatory fields, `subcategory` is optional).

We then tell `biblatex` what to doe with the new entry type

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{archive}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{archive}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{category}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{subcategory}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{box}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

This is very straightforward (and not very sophisticated at all): Just print all the fields separated by a space.

We will have to tell `biblatex` to use this datamodel via `datamodel=archives` (without the `.dbx` extension) in the loading-time options.

For sorting, we can define a custom sorting scheme called `archive`.

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{archive}{
  \sort{
    \field{archive}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{category}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{subcategory}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{box}
  }
}
```

It sorts by `archive`, `category`, `subcategory`, `box` as one would expect.
In the bibliography, we use this sorting scheme by appending `sorting=archive` if necessary.

For citing in `authortitle-dw`, we have to redefine `cite:normal`

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:normal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifentrytype{archive}
         {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}%
                                 \AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
           {\ifnameundef{labelname}
             {}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
            \ifbool{cbx:omiteditor}
              {}
              {\ifnameundef{labelname}
                {\newunit
                 \usebibmacro{cite:byeditor}}
                {}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}%
    {\ifbool{cbx:shorthandibid}%
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
         {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
```

We just check whether the cited entry is of type `@archive`; if so, the whole citation is generated if needed (there is no such thing as a short form).*

In order to be able to separate the bibliography by archives we will define a new `bibcategory` for each `archive` like so

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{archive1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{archnew}
```

We then set up a check for the `archive`

```
\AtDataInput[archive]{
  \iffieldequalstr{archive}{Archive 1}
    {\addtocategory{archive1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}
  \iffieldequalstr{archive}{ArchNew}
    {\addtocategory{archnew}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}
}
```

This test just checks if the `archive` field contains a particular string and if so adds the entry to the appropriate category.

Printing a divided bibliography is then as easy as

```
\printbibliography[category=archive1,heading=subbibliography,title={Archive 1},sorting=archive]
\printbibliography[category=archnew,heading=subbibliography,title={Archive Newtown},sorting=archive]
\printbibliography[nottype=archive,heading=subbibliography]
```

The full example (obviously `archives.dbx` is created here by `filecontents` if you use the file productively you will have saved a copy of the file at the appropriate place)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
    style=authortitle-dw,
    firstfull=true,
    datamodel=archives,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@archive{test1,
  subcategory = {subcategory},
  archive     = {Archive 1},
  category    = {Category 1},
  box         = {Box1},
}
@archive{test2,
  subcategory = {subcategory},
  archive     = {Archive 1},
  category    = {Category 1},
  box         = {Box2},
}
@archive{test3,
  subcategory = {subcategory},
  archive     = {Archive 1},
  category    = {Category 2},
  box         = {Box2},
}
@archive{test5,
  subcategory = {Ru7},
  archive     = {ArchNew},
  category    = {FAS},
  box         = {321},
}
@article{test4,
  title   = {Something},
  author  = {Mueller, Claus},
  journal = {A Journal},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{archives.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{archives.dbx}[2014/04/02 supplement archive]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{category,subcategory,archive,box}
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[archive]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{archive}
    \constraintfield{category}
    \constraintfield{box}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{category}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{category}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{subcategory}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{subcategory}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{box}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{box}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{archive}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{archive}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{category}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{subcategory}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{box}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:normal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifentrytype{archive}
         {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}%
                                 \AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
           {\ifnameundef{labelname}
             {}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
            \ifbool{cbx:omiteditor}
              {}
              {\ifnameundef{labelname}
                {\newunit
                 \usebibmacro{cite:byeditor}}
                {}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}%
    {\ifbool{cbx:shorthandibid}%
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
         {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{archive1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{archnew}
\AtDataInput[archive]{
  \iffieldequalstr{archive}{Archive 1}
    {\addtocategory{archive1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}
  \iffieldequalstr{archive}{ArchNew}
    {\addtocategory{archnew}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}
}


\DeclareSortingScheme{archive}{
  \sort{
    \field{archive}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{category}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{subcategory}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{box}
  }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  Lorem\footcite{test3}
  ipsum\footcite{test3}
  dolor\footcite{test1}
  sit\footcite{test1}
  amet\footcite{test2}
  consecetur\footcite{test3}
  blah\footcite{test1}
  bleurg\footcite{test4}
  more\footcite{test5}

  \clearpage

  Trallala\footcite{test1}

  \printbibliography[category=archive1, heading=subbibliography, title={Archive 1}, sorting=archive]
  \printbibliography[category=archnew, heading=subbibliography, title={Archive Newtown}, sorting=archive]
  \printbibliography[nottype=archive, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote citations]
[image: split bibliography: now sorted correctly]

* One could implement short forms as well, of you like.

Comment: That's AWESOME! Works flawless! I have just one further question. Is it possible to get the material in the right order?

Comment: Arrg. I could not edit anymore. Is ist possible to get the sub-bibliography of the different archives in an ascending order?  In your example of course it is, but I think thats because you cited the sources accordingly.  In my case I have for example `StaS Ho1 T8 73`, then `StaS Ho1 T7 962` followed by `StaS Ho1 T8 85` and next is then `StaS Ho1 T7 945`.  The best solution would be of course if everything could be in the right, ascending order. First all sorted by category and then (by subcategory and then) by box number.

Comment: @Sascha I have added a custom sorting scheme for the bibliography, you now have to load the archive `\printbibliographies` with `sorting=archive`.

Comment: @Sascha If it works for you, you might consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should rather be a comment to moewe's answer. It only comes as an answer, because I'm not yet allowed to comment.

As the whole signature should appear in the footnotes every time an archival source is cited or, if it's cited two or more times in a row, it should be fully replaced by `Ibid.`, wouldn't it be much easier to simply treat all the information (e.g. archive, shelf, box, document no.) as just the title of said source? For this purpose, you could use an already existing entry type, e.g. `@misc`:

```
@misc {test1,
    title = {ArchNew Ho1 Ru8 356}
}

@misc {test2,
    title = {ArchNew FAS Ru7 321}
}
```

This should produce the desired results for the footnotes without the need to alter the code.

To solve the second problem concerning the appearance of the sources cited within the bibliography, it might indeed be helpful to create a different entry type for each archive (e.g. `@archnew`, `@archold` etc.). That way, the different sources cited could be arranged according to their archive in the bibliography using the following commands:

```
\printbibliography[type=archnew,heading=subbibliography,title={Archive Newtown}]
\printbibliography[type=archold,heading=subbibliography,title={Archive Oldtown}]
```

I don't really have the possibility to test this right now, so it might be incomplete.

Comment: To be honest, I had not really thought about just using the title field (I like the more natural/semantic approach of using fields that actually *say* what they contain). Regarding your idea for the bibliography: I would not use entry types for that, but `keyword`s or `entrysubtype`s or even `\defbibcheck` for the `archive` field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nicolas. This was actually my first idea too. But it did not really work out very well. I wrote that driver myself (or better tried to). An it worked poorly. The first citation (first full) always worked very well - but not the later omes.