# How get rid of duplicate entries in tweaked bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex-dw

I'm trying to get a bibliography driver working correctly. I used the code from this previous post, with some minor changes: [Need help configuring entry type driver for biblatex-dw. Different citation style sa for different entry types](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168898/need-help-configuring-entry-type-driver-for-biblatex-dw-different-citation-styl)

My version is in the MWE below.

What I want to accomplish, that the previous question did not deal with, is to suppress one of the bib entries (e.g. the one I call `box` in my MWE. The suppression works fine, but the result is that I get two or more similar lines in the bibliography. Is there a way to get a list of unique entries, while still suppressing the `box` field?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=authortitle-dw,
    firstfull=true,
    datamodel=archives,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@archive{test1,
  subcategory = {Foo},
  category     = {StateArchive},
  box         = {130},
}

@archive{test2,
  subcategory = {Foo},
  category     = {StateArchive},
  box         = {131},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{archives.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{archives.dbx}[2014/04/02 supplement archive]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{category,subcategory,archive,box}
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[archive]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{archive}
    \constraintfield{category}
    \constraintfield{box}
  }
}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{category}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{category}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{subcategory}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{subcategory}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{archive}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{box}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[archive]{box}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{archive}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{archive}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{category}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{subcategory}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{box}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:normal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifentrytype{archive}
         {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}%
                                 \AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
           {\ifnameundef{labelname}
             {}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
            \ifbool{cbx:omiteditor}
              {}
              {\ifnameundef{labelname}
                {\newunit
                 \usebibmacro{cite:byeditor}}
                {}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}%
    {\ifbool{cbx:shorthandibid}%
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
         {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{archive1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{archnew}
\AtDataInput[archive]{
  \iffieldequalstr{archive}{Archive 1}
    {\addtocategory{archive1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}
  \iffieldequalstr{archive}{ArchNew}
    {\addtocategory{archnew}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}
}


\DeclareSortingScheme{archive}{
  \sort{
    \field{archive}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{category}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{subcategory}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{box}
  }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  more\footcite{test1}
  more\footcite{test2}

  \clearpage
\DeclareFieldFormat[archive]{box}{}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Current output (bibliography only, as it's the one I'm having problems with):

[image: bibliography]

So, I only want one line, not two similar lines.

Edit: to be clear, I need the box field to be visible in the footnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only comes as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

I doubt there's an easy way to achieve automatically what you'd like to achieve, because those different entries you're citing are treated by biblatex as just what they are: different entries that happen to have the same content.

What you could do would be to manually suppress every entry citing sources from the same archive but one using the `skipbib` option, e.g.:

```
@archive{test1,
  subcategory  = {Foo},
  category     = {StateArchive},
  box          = {130}
}

@archive{test2,
  subcategory  = {Foo},
  category     = {StateArchive},
  box          = {131},
  options      = {skipbib=true}
}

@archive{test3,
  subcategory  = {Foo},
  category     = {StateArchive},
  box          = {132},
  options      = {skipbib=true}
}
```

This works fine if you only have a limited number of archival sources you cite from but could be really painful otherwise.

Comment: Yay! Thanks Nicholas. That works for me, despite the little extra effort needed.