# Manually adding manuscript sources on the final bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have cited all the manuscript sources of my doctoral dissertation manually using \footnote. I am now wondering how to include these sources in the final bibliography separately. (1. Primary sources. 1.1. Unpublished primary sources. 1.2. Published primary sources. 2. Secondary sources.) Is there a way to do so manually? Or is it better to create a new .bib file with the list of manuscript documents under the category @misc of my package `biblatex-chicago`?

I have added an example of the result I would like to obtain:
[image: bibliography]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what you mean by "manually"? You have regular non-manuscript citations in a `.bib` file and you're using `biblatex-chicago` for them, but none of your manuscript sources are currently in a `.bib` file at all? And the final output you want will be your regular bibliography and then a "manuscript" bibliography organized in the way you say?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Non manuscript citations are in a `.bib` file with the exception of manuscript documents. A typical "manual" citation would look like: `\footnote{ASFi MP 4463 f.43r-v}`

Comment: I'm not sure what the "manuscript bibliography" would look like, maybe you can also create it manually (since your citations are also created manually, that would also make sense). If you want the bibliography to be created automatically (there is no problem splitting the bibliographies by type) it is quite beneficial to have a `.bib` file with the proper entries. Would you be able to show what you have so far as well as a "mock-up" of what you would like to get?

Comment: I have added an image of the result I would like to obtain. Concerning what I have so far, it is merely an automated final bibliography of all the secondary sources.

Comment: So `primarysource.bib` does not exist? Published manuscripts (whatever these are) are also only cited that way in footnotes?

Comment: You should consider whether [biblatex-manuscripts-philology](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-manuscripts-philology?lang=en) is an option. (However, as I understand it, the package is better geared toward critical editing tasks than mere bibliography.) Alternatively, it is possible to define your own entry type, say `@manuscript`, and 'bibliography driver' for it. This would be the best way to integrate it into the other parts of the bibliography.

Comment: You could also have a look at [Biblatex: Citing complex nested unpublished sources](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287044/35864) or [Need help configuring entry type driver for biblatex-dw. Different citation style sa for different entry types](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168898/35864) for some other `biblatex` solutions.

Comment: @jon Many thanks for the comment! I didn't know about biblatex-manuscripts-philology, I'll test it this week-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything that is in your `.bib` file already it's simple to group those citations using `biblatex`.  See [Sectioning bibliography by type of referred item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/2693)  for a basic example. Since you've manually entered the unpublished sources, and the format you want them in isn't terribly conducive to a `.bib` solution, I suggest organizing them in a CSV file and using `datatool` to print them.

The following document as proof of concept does what you want.  First, the CSV file. It has the following column structure:

```
ArchiveName   ArchiveAbbrev   SourceName   SourcePrefix   SourceNumber
```

So a single row corresponds to an individual item:

```
"Archivo di Stato di Firenze", "ASFi",  "Mediceo del Principato", "Filze",  "810"
```

In the sample document I've used simple sectioning to format the headings, but you could do this any way you like really.  The code is quite simple: I read through the file and produce headings as needed, otherwise I output a comma and a source number.  There is no sorting done of the entries, as this is easy to do in Excel or OpenOffice.

```
\begin{filecontents}{manuscripts.csv}
"ArchiveName","ArchiveAbbrev","SourceName","SourcePrefix","SourceNumber"
"Archivo di Stato di Firenze","ASFi","Mediceo del Principato","Filze",810
"Archivo di Stato di Firenze","ASFi","Mediceo del Principato","Filze",4323
"Archivo di Stato di Firenze","ASFi","Miscellanea Medicea","Filze",2634
"Archivo di Stato di Firenze","ASFi","Strozzi","Filze",480
"Archivo di Stato di Mantova","ASMn","Archivio Gonzaga",,"b1117"
"Archivo di Stato di Mantova","ASMn","Archivio Gonzaga",,"b1140"
"Archivo di Stato di Mantova","ASMn","Archivio Gonzaga",,"b1920"
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloadrawdb{manuscripts}{manuscripts.csv}
\def\lastsource{}
\def\lastarch{}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{manuscripts}{\archive=ArchiveName,\archabbrev=ArchiveAbbrev,\sourcename=SourceName,\sourceprefix=SourcePrefix,\sourcenum=SourceNumber}{%
\DTLifstringeq{\archive}{\lastarch}
    {\DTLifstringeq{\sourcename}{\lastsource}
        {, \sourcenum}%
        {\let\lastsource\sourcename
         \subsection{\sourcename}
         \DTLifnullorempty{\sourceprefix}{}{\sourceprefix~}\sourcenum}}
    {\let\lastarch\archive
     \let\lastsource\sourcename
     \section{\archive\DTLifnullorempty{\archabbrev}{}{ (\archabbrev)}}
     \subsection{\sourcename}
     \DTLifnullorempty{\sourceprefix}{}{\sourceprefix~}\sourcenum}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!