# Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex-gost package

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

When trying to use the solution for author highlighting from [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864) it turned out that it perfectly works with default styles but stops working with `biblatex-gost` ones (well, at least with `gost-numeric` style I need, others were not tested). What should be changed to make it working?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}% If one deletes "gost-" all becomes OK

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

  @incollection{Silva:2014a,
  title={Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
  author={Carlos F. M. Silva and Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B. and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
  booktitle={Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
  publisher={Springer Science+Business Media},
  year=2014,
  address={New York, USA},
  editor={Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
  pages={105-156},
  doi={10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
  isbn={978-1-4614-8056-3},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}% or use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}%
}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\xpretobibmacro{name:last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:first-last}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:last-first}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:first-last}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:last-first}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{5e1df516fe8816ee66169b8616522816}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Silva:2014a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This answer was updated to work with newer versions of `biblatex-gost`. See the edit history for older versions.

`biblatex-gost` defines its own name formats for authors called `headingname:family-given`, so you need to patch this macro instead.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newcommand*{\doboldhashes}[1]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{#1}
    {\bfseries\listbreak}
    {}}%

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}{%
  \forlistloop{\doboldhashes}{\boldnames}%
}

\xpretobibmacro{headingname:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{headingname:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{5e1df516fe8816ee66169b8616522816}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Silva:2014a,
  title={Radio Resource Management for Device-to-Device Communications in Long Term Evolution Networks},
  author={Carlos F. M. Silva and Silva, Jr., Jos\'{e} Mairton B. and Tarcisio F. Maciel},
  booktitle={Resource Allocation and {MIMO} for {4G} and Beyond},
  publisher={Springer Science+Business Media},
  year=2014,
  address={New York, USA},
  editor={Francisco Rodrigo Porto Cavalcanti},
  pages={105-156},
  doi={10.1007/978-1-4614-8057-0_3},
  isbn={978-1-4614-8056-3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Silva:2014a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completing the answer above: `name:delim` affects the delimiter before the name, so depending on the desired effect, it may be necessary to patch it.

If not patched, the delimiter before boldcased names will be bold; if patched with `\normalfont`, it will be regular.