# Is there a workaround for this limitation of \patchcmd?

Tags: macros, etoolbox, patching

The `\patchcmd` command of the well-known [`etoolbox`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) package has a minor limitation: Patching seems to fail whenever `\patchcmd` is used in the argument of another command and the search/replacement texts themselves include references to arguments. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\test#1{#1test}

\ifdefparam{\test}{%
  \patchcmd{\test}{#1}{#1-}{\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}%
}{%
}

\show\test

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Here, the problem can easily be solved using the following trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\test#1{#1test}

\ifdefparam{\test}\iftrue\iffalse
  \patchcmd{\test}{#1}{#1-}{\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}
\fi

\show\test

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

But the question remains: Is there a generally applicable workaround for this limitation of `\patchcmd`?

Comment: Related: [How can I use `\patchcmd` with commands with optional arguments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24245/5764)

Comment: The trick works because you're not really in the argument to a command.

Comment: @egreg: And, most probably, the trick won’t work with every test macro. But till today, I haven’t known a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `\xpatchcmd` command provided by the (experimental) [`regexpatch`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/regexpatch/regexpatch.pdf) package. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\def\test#1{#1test}

\ifdefparam{\test}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\test}{#1}{#1-}{\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}%
}{%
}

\show\test

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

According to its documentation, the `regexpatch` package is an advanced sibling of the [`xpatch`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch/xpatch.pdf) package and is intended to replace the latter as soon as the underlying LaTeX3 packages from the `l3experimental` bundle have become stable.

Note that `\xpatchcmd` as implemented by the `xpatch` package shows the same limitation as `\patchcmd`. This might be explained by the following sentence from the `regexpatch` package documentation:

> The package is now completely independent of `etoolbox`.

Comment: This just shows the usage of `\xpatchcmd` provided by [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch). Perhaps you could elaborate on the difference between the functionality supported by `xpatch` and that of `regexpatch`.

Comment: You can also do `\regexpatchcmd{\test}{(\cP.1)}{\1-}{}{}` that won't give any problem even in the *definition* of another command: the regular expression `\cP.1` denotes any category 6 character (`#`) followed by `1`; it will replaced by itself (`\1`) followed by a hyphen.

Comment: @Werner With `xpatch` the result would be exactly the same as with `etoolbox`, because the package eventually uses `\patchcmd`. This is not the case with `regexpatch` that uses a completely different system.

Comment: The fixed version of `regexpatch` is on its way to CTAN.

Comment: This code does not compile.